# Iterate over an object and replace properties with setters and getters

Tags: javascript, iteration, getter-setter

I want to be able to have a function that will replace all of an objects properties with a setter and getter.

```
function myFunction(obj){
var private={};
for(var i in obj){
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(Ii){
private[i]=obj[i]
delete obj[i]
Object.defineProperty(obj, i, {
set:(function(i){return function(val){private[i]=val}})(i),
set:(function(i){return function(){return private[i]}})(i)
})}
}
return obj
}
```

Would this work or should I use a different method to iterate over the object, could this style of storing the data in a seperate object also cause issues.

Comment: Note that you're replacing both inherited and "own" properties, which seems odd. Did you mean just to replace "own" properties?

Comment: Yes I did, I'll edit it, thank you

Comment: Side note: Please use indentation and spaces to make code clearer. Ramming everything together (even if it were indented) makes things hard to read.

Comment: Sure, I'll try indent more in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the data in a separate object is fine.

I would simplify the code a bit by using `Object.keys`, **assuming** that you didn't really mean to replace inherited properties (`for-in` enumerates both "own" and inherited properties; `Object.keys` just gives you an array of "own" enumerable properties):

```
function myFunction(obj){
    var private = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        private[key] = obj[key];
        // No need for the `delete`
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            set: function(value) {
                private[key] = value;
            },
            get: function() {
                return private[key];
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true // Or leave it off if you don't want the
                               // property reconfigured
        });
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Notes:

- By using the `forEach` callback, we make the `get`/`set` function closures over `key` and so can avoid creating temporary wrapper functions.
- `enumerable` defaults to `false`; I'm assuming you don't want to change the enumerability of the properties, so I've added `enumerable: true`
- You had `set` twice, rather than `get` and `set`

Comment: How will the getter treat methods of the object? Will calling them work like expected?

Comment: @user7951676: Properties that refer to functions will work just fine with the above (including having the right `this` if they're normal functions and called via the object).